# What are the "alternatives" to Heketi for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs

I have built a working GlusterFS cluster, and now I want to make a Kubernetes StorageClass that uses it.  I see a number of tutorials and documentation pointing to [Heketi](https://github.com/heketi/heketi) as the provisioner engine.

Looking at that page, however, it has the following admonition:

> It has been well over a year since we first entered maintenance mode.
> To anyone looking at creating a new install using Heketi: we highly
> encourage you to look at other appraoches to dynamic storage
> provisioning, especially if you're not already very familiar with
> Heketi/Gluster.

This doesn't seem like something I want to invest a lot of time in learning or deploying.

So what are the "other approaches" that are being referred to?  Can anyone provide some pointers?   Web searches don't seem to come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please look towards https://kadalu.io/
(maintainers of GlusterFS project)